# Is MPS module available for Odoo v8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

MPS(Master Production Schedule) which is a part of the MRP - manufacturing module has odoo 10 enterprise edition.

Would like to know if MPS is available for odoo v8 community edition. Or is there any other alternative instead of MPS?

Answer (score 0):

In below link you will find "MPS - Sale forecast" module.
https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/procurement_sale_forecast/

Also you will find other odoo mrp modules in git repository.

https://github.com/odoomrp/odoomrp-wip